# Python Pandas: condition to apply null

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I would like to transform my numeric variable that If it exceeds 1,000 value then it should be null or NA. Otherwise still use the value. Below is my code.

```
df['PREMIUM'] = pd.to_numeric( df["PREMIUM"])
df['PREMIUM_V2'] = np.where(df['PREMIUM']>1000,np.NaN,df['PREMIUM'])
```

I tried this but it makes my PREMIUM_V2 not a numeric value. It became just an object.

Comment: It should be of type float, not object.

Comment: Yes. Is my np.where code right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it should be used

Comment: please provide a reproducible input

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PREMIUM': [0,1,100,10000]})

df['PREMIUM2'] = df['PREMIUM'].mask(df['PREMIUM'].gt(1000))
```

output:

```
   PREMIUM  PREMIUM2
0        0       0.0
1        1       1.0
2      100     100.0
3    10000       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your question if you want to change the value in the column
df['PREMIUM'] to NaN if the value greater than 1000 :

```
df['PREMIUM'] = pd.to_numeric( df["PREMIUM"])
df['PREMIUM'] = np.where(df['PREMIUM']>1000,df['PREMIUM'],np.NaN)
```

if you want to create a different column in the dataframe and keep the less than 1000 value as it is and change the value grater than 1000 as Nan you can use :

```
df['PREMIUM'] = pd.to_numeric( df["PREMIUM"])
df['PREMIUM_V2'] = np.where(df['PREMIUM']>1000,df['PREMIUM'],np.NaN)
```

note : numpy.where(condition, [dataframe], value)